# nested boxes pushed down by margin-top

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS properties being passed up to the parent element when the DIV is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351881/css-properties-being-passed-up-to-the-parent-element-when-the-div-is-empty)

I'm a newbie for CSS layout design.

What I'd like to do at the moment is that I want to make two Div boxes, one nested inside one another. Anyway, my problem is the top margin I set to the inner box didn't behave the way I wanted.

Pls take the portion of script below for example:

**[demo.html]**

```
<html>
    <header>
        <title>Mock-up page</title>
        <link href="stylesheets/demo.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css">

    </header>
    <body>
        <div id="box1">
            <div id="box2">div 2</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**[demo.css]**

```css
#box1{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px; 
    background-color:#0000FF;       
}

#box2{
    margin-top: 30px;
    background-color:#008000;
}
```

The effect it produced was it only pushed the outer box 30px down from body tag (left-sided in the picture), which wasn't what I had expected (right-sided in the picture).

[image]

What was the reason why this happened and how to correct the styling?

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680478/margin-top-push-outer-div-down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `margin-top` to `padding-top` will do what you want.

This is a know issue in many browsers.
When the first child of an element has a `margin-top` (no content before it) the margin overflow the top of the parent element and pushes it like in your case.

Other solutions exists, but all of them are a bit hacky:

- Apply a position: relative to the child and change the `margin-top` to a `margin-bottom` and apply `top: 20px;`;
- Create an element before the inner box with some content (&nbsp; can be used here) with `height: 0;` and `overflow: hidden;`;
- Set a `border-top: 1px solid transparent` or the same color of the background of the element (in this case, pay attention that the border is added to the height of the object;
- and so on...

Answer (score 0):

You could add `position: relative` to #box1 and `position: absolute` to #box2.

See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/q9XFa/1/)

[CSS Positions Explained](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/)

Comment: Good resource for beginners, but positioning is overkill in this case.

Comment: @rcdmk yep, you're right

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```css
#box1{
    display:block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px; 
    background-color:#0000FF;
    border:solid transparent 1px;    
}

#box2{
    margin-top: 30px;
    background-color:#008000;
} ​
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="box1">
    <div id="box2">div 2</div>
</div>​
```

If you keep the outer box empty (no text node) then it's doing this behavior and to be honest I didn't understand why, but I found it [**here**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins) why it does so and it's known as `collapsed margin` and I've added `border:solid transparent 1px;` to soleve the issue **but alternatively you can use padding for outer** `DIV`. Here is also an answer on [**SO**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351881/css-properties-being-passed-up-to-the-parent-element-when-the-div-is-empty).

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/W6P3C/1/)

Comment: Have in mind that this will increase the measures of the box by the border width for each side (eg.: `height` = `height` + `border-top-width` + `border-bottom-width` and `width` = `width` + `border-left-width` + `border-right-width`) in all major browsers (I think IE 6 and 7 don't)

Comment: I think padding of outer/parent div will be better solution.